# Unable to get pointer of structure C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Scenario is like there is GUI and Dll, GUI is in C#(WPF) and it is using c++ Dll and dll needs structure pointer of structure created in GUI for processing commands.

In Dll structure having fixed size array so same created in GUI also.

C++ structure

```
struct _TempData
{
    Int32 iOnFly_StepCalib;
    Int32 iOnFly_BiDiCalib;
    UNIT Unit;
    byte uiPrintDirection;

    Int16 siStep_Feed[20];
};
```

so In GUI(C#) structure is like...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct _TempData
{
    public Int32 iOnFly_StepCalib;
    public Int32 iOnFly_BiDiCalib;
    public UNIT Unit;
    public byte uiPrintDirection;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public Int16[] siStep_Feed;
};
```

and my c# code for getting this structure pointer is here

```
[DllImport("Dll12.dll")]
public static extern UIntPtr sendMessageToHSM(Int32 MSG, IntPtr CmdStruct);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _TempData tempData;
    tempData.iOnFly_BiDiCalib = 1;
    tempData.iOnFly_StepCalib = 2;
    tempData.uiPrintDirection = 1;
    tempData.Unit = UNIT.INCH;

    unsafe
    {
        void* tempdata1 = &tempData;
        sendMessageToHSM((int)HSM_COMMANDS.HSM_GUI_PC_UPDATE_STEP_CALIB, (IntPtr)tempdata1 );
    }
}
```

This error is showing...

```
Error   CS0208  Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('_TempData')
```

on commenting this line in structure

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
public Int16[] siStep_Feed;
```

then code is running fine.

I am new to C#.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That line has nothing to do with it

Comment: Yes right.. To solve this problem may be structure needs different formatting or there should be another way to take structure's address.

Comment: The [DllImport] declaration is unnecessarily clumsy, use `ref _TempData` instead of IntPtr so the pinvoke marshaler will convert the structure.   Making the struct blittable is possible, but you'd have to declare the array as `fixed Int16 siStep_Feed[20];`  Channeling why you might like IntPtr, If you used it so you can pass IntPtr.Zero then use the `class` keyword instead to declare the structure, now you drop `ref` and can pass null.  Careful with Pack=4, not often correct albeit that it doesn't seem to matter here (can't see what UNIT might mean).

Comment: sendMessageToHSM is a generic function to send all structure to dll it's not like _TempData will be sent to dll always, So that's why used IntPtr. 

fixed Int16 siStep_Feed[20]; also a way to declare fixed size array but some times I need to read data from file So I read file in byte[] and then used Marshal.PtrToStructure to copy data from byte[] to structure So after coping data there is a problem all element in structure are OK(else array elements) but array having data only on 1st Index rest all index of array having null value.

Comment: In Dll sendMessageToHSM declaration is like 

WPARAM EXPORTED_DLL_FUNCTION sendMessageToHSM( INT32 MSG, void *CmdStruct )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code, also `unsafe` keyword is no use here

I believe what you might be looking for is

```
// get the size
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(tempData);

// Create some unmanaged memory 
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

// marshal the structure to pointer
Marshal.StructureToPtr(tempData, ptr, false);

// call the funky api
sendMessageToHSM((int)HSM_COMMANDS.HSM_GUI_PC_UPDATE_STEP_CALIB, ptr);

// get the result if there is any
_TempData tempData2 = (_TempData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(_TempData));

// clean up the memory
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Also in C# we don't name types with an underscore

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I had already tried this one. And there is one more thing is that DLL is using this pointer parallely and if we free pointer in GUI using Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr); then Application will crash or will get wrong data.

Comment: I used unsafe because we can only get the pointer of managed structure in unsafe context.